# Print a center aligned triangle along with upside down triangle in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to print center aligned triangle along with upside down triangle. Output should be this.

```
           1
          121
         12321
        1234321
       123454321
        1234321
         12321
          121
           1
```

Though its showing correctly numbers and upper half of the triangle properly centered aligned, its not showing lower half of the triangle in center alignment.Below is my code.

```
public class Pro1point1
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  int i,j,k,l,space=29;
  for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
    //First print the upper half triangle. 
    for(j=1;j<=space;j++){
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(k=1;k<=i;k++){
      System.out.print(k);
    }
    for(l=i-1;l>=1;l--){
      System.out.print(l);
    }
    space--;
    System.out.println();
  }
  //Now Print the lower half triangle.

  space=29;
  for(i=4;i>=1;i--){
   for(j=space;j>=1;j--){
     System.out.print("");
   }
   for(k=1;k<=i;k++){
    System.out.print(k);
   }
   for(l=i-1;l>=1;l--){
    System.out.print(l);
   }
   space++;
   System.out.println();
  }
}
}
```

It shows me like this.

[image: My Output is like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the second for loop, you have to use:

```
System.out.print(" ");
```

instead of

```
System.out.print("");
```

Update:

You can "debug" this magical offset by using `System.out.print("X")` and a lower value for `space`. Take a look at how many `X` are printed on every line.

What happens after the middle line?
What happens when you replace `space=29;` with `space+=2;`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working now. Bit confuse why did we take space=26? Can you please explain me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line `System.out.print("");`

Notice that you print empty string instead space character

Replace it with `System.out.print(" ");`

Comment: Oh Yes.Correct. But its still showing slightly lower half of the triangle right align from center.